# Equivalent of width:-webkit-fill-available in Internal Explorer

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have searched for a while and i couldn't find the below equivalent for IE support. Please someone help me to fix the issue.

```
width: -moz-available;          /* Mozilla */
width: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Webkit */
width: -o-available;  /* OPera */
```

Answer (score 0):

The min-width: 100% declared at the start will be used by browsers which ignore both the -moz and -webkit-prefixed declarations or do not support -moz-available or -webkit-fill-available.

```
min-width: 100%; in IE equivalent to  
width: -moz-available;          /* Mozilla */
width: -webkit-fill-available;  /* Webkit */  
width: -o-available;  /* OPera */
```